# "Way too long" - Allowed or Disallowed?

Tags: discussion, policy, answers

During my time at PPCG I've seen many answers which don't post the byte count, but instead put "way too long". For example, [Thomas Kwa's answer here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60257/30525). I have also seen this on a plethora of Java answers.

Personally I find this rather irritating as I still want to see the answer's byte count. So what's the community's view on this?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a byte count.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Submissions for code golf should include an accurate byte count. Without it, the submission should be considered invalid since it isn't properly scored.

The default course of action in this case should be to notify the user with a comment, optionally linking back to this meta post.

Comment: "The default course of action in this case should be to notify the user with a comment": why not just edit in the byte count? ["When should I edit posts? Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. Editing is encouraged! Some common reasons to edit are:... to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it; to correct minor mistakes"](/help/privileges/edit)

Comment: @msh210 It should be the responsibility of the answerer to ensure that their submission abides by our rules.

Comment: @msh210 There are two reasons why we might edit. The most obvious one is when we can make the post better. But another reason is to *correct the behavior* of the submitter so next time they do it properly. Our moderation privileges are here not just to make the individual posts better, but to make the site better. We should use them to that end.

Comment: I would edit the answer and leave a comment explaining that, in the future, the author should score his or her answer. This improves the post *and* makes the site better.

Comment: It _should_ be emphasized `should` means it is recommended, _expected_ in general. It does not mean `must`, i. e. occasional non-observance of this recommendation is no violation. [RFC 2119](https://Datatracker.IETF.org/doc/html/rfc2119)